# ImageMagick: Resize image (rectangle to square); keep aspect ratio of main object

Tags: image, imagemagick, command-line-interface, thumbnails

I have portrait and landscape JPEG images.

I want to make square thumbnails with white background from all of them. I need to keep the aspect ratio of all images and reduce the larger border to 200px.

I want to use ImageMagick (CLI) but I don't know how to do that. Any idea ?

[image: Thumbnail generation]

Here is the individual images :

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]

Comment: Please give the individual images.

Comment: @MarkSetchell : What do you mean?

Comment: You have provided a merged image of the start image and the result on a black background, rather than the starting image on its own.

Comment: You ***cannot*** resize from rectangle to square and at the same time keep your aspect ratio! What your example image *looks* like is a two-step process: ***(1)*** *extent* the rectangle image's background to make the new image square; ***(2)*** scale the big square image to a small square image (keeping aspect ratio). -- (The reverse order of steps is also possible: ***(1)*** first resize the rectangle, ***(2)*** then extent it to a square...) -- You can pack both steps into a single IM command, though.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think you need this:

```
convert -background white -gravity center   \
    input.jpg -resize 200x200 -extent 200x200 result.jpg
```

Comment: Thank you. For PNG image, I swap white to transparent.

Comment: @MarkSetchell It does not work in ImageMagick 6.9.11-60 Q16 x86_64 2021-01-25 provided in ubuntu 22.04.